# Defining handler in-line when defining logger

Tags: python, logging, handler

In the below example, I am trying to add the handler `RotatingFileHandler(LOGGING_BASE_DIR + 'application.log', maxBytes=5e6, backupCount=10)` to the logger `device`, but I get the error `ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'device': Unable to add handler <logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler object at 0x1031beb10>: <logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler object at 0x1031beb10>`.

I realize that I am defining one handler as a string and the other as a handler object so that may be why it is not working. However, is there some way to define the handler in-line in the config, or do I need to add the handler itself to the config along with the `console` handler?

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'incremental': False,

    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'debug',
            'stream': sys.stdout
        },
    },

    'loggers': {
        'device': {
            'handlers': [
                'console',
                RotatingFileHandler(LOGGING_BASE_DIR + 'application.log', maxBytes=5e6, backupCount=10),
            ],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
           'propagate': True
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `RotatingFileHandler` next to the one you labelled with id `console` in the `handlers` section, as described in the [logging dictionary schema details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details).

If this json dictionary is loaded from a file however, you won't be able to use the `LOGGING_BASE_DIR + 'application.log'` for the filename, because `LOGGING_BASE_DIR` is not defined (and not a valid string in this context). You should replace it in this case with a full and valid path name.
If you are generating this dictionary from within a python script (the same one that will likely call `logging.config.dictConfig()`), then you can use it though, provided you have defined `LOGGING_BASE_DIR` previously and it points to a valid path. I'd use `os.path.join` though, rather than `+`.

Your dictionary could look like this then:

```
MYDIR = '/tmp/log'
LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'incremental': False,

    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
        },
        'rotatingfile': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(MYDIR, 'application.log'),
            'maxBytes': 5e6,
            'backupCount': 10
        }
    },

    'loggers': {
        'device': {
            'handlers': [
                'console',
                'rotatingfile'
            ],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
           'propagate': True
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess the answer to my question is that I need to define the handler further up in the dict and then reference it when I define the logger.